# Prove that the volume of a cylinder is $\pi a^2 h$ using triple integration and spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

We have a cylinder of radius $a$ and height $h.$ We need to prove its volume to be equal to $\pi a^2 h$ using triple integral and spherical coordinates.

The best way to solve this problem is to divide the cylinder to two volume regions, the first region is the one defined by $\phi$ to range from $0$ to $\arctan(\frac{a}{h})$ and the second region is the one defined by $\phi$ to range from $\arctan(\frac{a}{h})$ till $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Surley, for both regions $\theta$ will vary from $0$ till $2\pi$. However, I tried many times to find the proper limits for the radius for each region but I failed. So how do I properly define the radius for each region ?

Edit : I know the limits of each region for the radius $r= 0$ till $a\secθ$ and $r= 0$ till $b\cscθ$ but my question exactly is how to drive them ?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: The equations for vertical and horizontal lines in polar coordinate are $r=a \sec \theta$ and $r=b\csc \theta.$  You can adapt these readily.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok

Comment: @B.Goddard Please explain how do you drive them

Comment: Start with $y=a$ is the same as $r\sin \theta = a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that to find the volume of a cylinder use cylindrical coordinates.

But you want to use spherical.

Your boundaries

$x^2 + y^2 = a^2\\
z = 0\\
z = h$

$x = \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y = \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = \rho\cos \phi$

$\rho^2\cos^2 \theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\sin^2 \theta\sin^2\phi = a^2\\
\rho^2\sin^2\phi = a^2\\
\rho = a\csc\phi$

$\rho\cos \phi = h\\
\rho = h\sec \phi$

$a\csc\phi = h\sec \phi\\
\tan\phi = \frac ah$

$\int_\limits0^{2\pi}\int_\limits0^{\arctan \frac {a}{h}}\int_\limits0^{h\sec \phi} \rho^2\sin \phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta\\ + \int_\limits0^{2\pi}\int_\limits{\arctan \frac {a}{h}}^\frac {\pi}{2}\int_\limits0^{a\csc \phi} \rho^2\sin \phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

Comment: How did you drive the limits of upper limits of the radius for each region ?

Comment: @Johnadams Did you ask this question before I completed my last edit?  Is it all clear now?

Comment: Yes , Thank you very much.